# dompdf v0.6.1 header/footer script not working in php $output = string

Tags: pdf, dompdf

Using DOMPDF to create pdf and attach it to email. That is working fine.

Trying to add header/footer and have seen the instructions, but I'm not converting from an html file, I'm making the pdf from a string in php that contains html.

So when I include the script type="text/php" etc, it is going into a var.

Like so

```
$op .= '<script type="text/php">

    if ( isset($pdf) ) {

      $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("verdana", "bold");
      $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "Header: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));

    }
    </script>';
```

But this doesn't appear to create headers/footers the created pdf file.

Comment: Have you enabled script support in dompdf by setting the `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` configuration constant to true?

Comment: Hi BrianS - thanks for the reply.  I updated the library - i think from the github repo - and it is all working fine now.

Comment: For completeness, I'll add as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When using embedded (inline) scripts make sure to enable processing of those scripts in your dompdf configuration.

For v0.6.x or earlier set the `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` configuration constant to true in your configuration file (dompdf_config.custom.inc.php or dompdf_config.inc.php).

For v0.7.x or newer call `$dompdf->set_option('isPhpEnabled', true)` before you process your document.